# whether rpcrt4.dll is a open source/ free library? can I bundle that library to my application

Tags: c++, rpc, uuid

I want to generate UUID in windows platform, So I planned to uses rpcrt4.dll in my application. I have a doubt whether rpcrt4.dll is a free library / open source, and can I use (bundle) it in my application?

Answer (score 1):

rpcrt4.dll is a standard Windows system library.  If your target is a Windows system, it should already be in place.

Comment: And distributing it yourself is _probably_ against licence terms.